# Publishing Photos via Instagram API gets error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I'm using this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing to publish a photo on `Instagram`. First I get a long-term access token for these scopes`user_profile,user_media,instagram_graph_user_profile,instagram_content_publish,instagram_basic,pages_show_list` then I try to publish a photo with `php` as below:

```
    $accessToken = 'IGQVJXVUp6YjA1LTI2M0dEa3NKU2ZAxdHhrZA1RZAOFVjdTlZANVRhaGR4dkNva1Bkc0NfbzhETU0tNU8tQ3hEbUI5cE1OTzI3M19zQ1JGMVNta2pKZAmVpSF94bFhBdE9LejNyaHZAlbFB';
    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/178414019085321/media';
    $method = 'POST';
    $queryString = "?image_url=https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg?hmac=rcadCENKh4rD6MAp6V_ma-AyWv641M4iiOpe1RyFHeI&caption=%23BronzFonz";
    $header = array('Authorization:bearer ' . $accessToken);
        
    $curl = curl_init();
    
$options = array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url.$queryString,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] => $header;
);
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $result = json_decode($response, true);
        
    print_r($result);
```

I get this errror:

```
  Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => Unsupported post request. Object with ID '178414019085321' does not exist,
 cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api [type] => GraphMethodException [code] => 100 [error_subcode] => 33 [fbtrace_id] => AAg5OYWbVyF1_DBOueclLBC ) )
```

178414019085321 is a valid user id of a business `Instagram` account.